# I'm not sure _app.js is being detected by Nextjs; Error: useSession must be wrapped in a <SessionProvider />

Tags: reactjs, next.js, auth0

I've been following a couple of tutorials about Nextjs, Prisma, and Auth0. My problem is that, after trying to create the login/logout buttons on my header (by adding `import { useSession, signIn, signOut } from "next-auth/react"` to the `header.js` file), Next.js presents the following error `` Error: [next-auth]: \`useSession\` must be wrapped in a \<SessionProvider /> ``. I've tried creating the `_app.js` file at the root folder, then at `/pages/_app.js`, and lastly at `/app/_app.js`. None of these worked.

This are the contents of my`_app.js file:`

```
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react"

export default function App({
  Component,
  pageProps: { session, ...pageProps },
}) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={session}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </SessionProvider>
  )
}
```

How do I make sure Next is detecting and using it? I think the file is being ignored somehow.

I tried changing the location of the `_app.js` file from the root folder of the project to `/pages/_app.js` and finally to `app/_app.js`. I also tried deleting the `.next` folder and rerunning the server but it didn't work.

**Update 1:**
Next.js version I'm using: v13.4.4

**Update 2:**
I've added a `console.log()` function to the `_app.js` file and it's being printed to the terminal, but not on Firefox. Does it mean `_app.js` is being detected normally or is there a problem?

**I (kinda) fixed it! Check my answer down below. It doesn't work when deployed to Vercel, though.**

Comment: What version of next do you use? It should work, are you using typescript? Try to rename _app.js to _app.jsx

Comment: I'm using Next.js v13.4.4. I tried renaming `_app.js` to `_app.tsx` and changing the contents of the file. I restarted my IDE and the server but nothing changed and I still have the same error.

Comment: Have you tried clearing cache on firefox? do you have "shields on"? if so, turn it off and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've fixed it I decided to forget about _app.js and put everything on my custom layout.js file. I still need to test if users will remain logged because header.js is outside layout.js.

**How I solved it**: I added

```
'use client'
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";
```

to `layout.js` (the file that comes with Next.js by default) and passed session in the parameters of the function that's being "exported" (export default function RootLayout). Then I wrapped all the return() parameters with .

Here's part of the code:

```
export default function RootLayout({ children, session }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <SessionProvider session={session}>
        <body>{children}</body>
      </SessionProvider>
    </html>
  )
}
```

**Important part:** Next won't allow you to export the metadata if you're using the `'use client'` option, so you'll need to delete `export const metadata = {...` from your code.

**Update**: For some reason, it doesn't work on Vercel (even though it does locally). I'll try to fix it and then I'll update my answer. **TL;DR:** This solution works locally, but not when deployed to Vercel.